# mac osx, git mergetool, diffmerge, command not found

Tags: macos, bash, diffmerge

I installed DiffMerge in Applications folder. 
I can't get DiffMerge run on its own, nor when I use `git mergetool`
My PATH variable:

```
/Applications/DiffMerge.app:/Applications/:/Applications/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin$$$:/usr/X11/bin
```

What am I missing? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac App bundles have the executables in the folder:

```
Contents/MacOS/
```

([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)).

So your path should be:

```
/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/bin:...etc
```

Having `/Applications/` in the path is completely pointless.